# Symfony - Setting new user Role

Tags: php, function, symfony, role

I defined new role in security.yml

```
ROLE_NEW: ROLE_NEW
```

and then set up the path

```
 - { path: ^/admin/staff, role: ROLE_STAFF } into access control.
```

I wrote a function that will return a user with that exact role on specific page after login

```
/** 
  * @Route("/staff", name="staff") 
  * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response 
  * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_STAFF')") 
  */
public function getNewDashboard()
{
    return $this->render('@AdminTemplates/admin/new_dashboard.html.twig');
}
```

but after login it redirect on the same dashboard as other users. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First the roles don't declare, only put it in access control (this part you do it well). The ROLE_XX: ROLE_XX is only below role_hierarchy. Next, we need see your route for getNewDashboard() to help you.

Comment: I just defined this, a did't defined anything else?

Comment: Please edit your post and show us your route

Comment: /**
     * @Route("/staff", name="staff")
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_STAFF')")
     */